# How does the Workshop's vehicle repair feature work?

Tags: state-of-decay

The [Workshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR34p.jpg)'s bonuses are described as:

> - Real Workshop - Automatically Repair Body and Tire damage for vehicles parked overnight.
> - Construction Expertise - +100% Construction Rate. REQUIRES TOOLS EXPERT.

So, if I have a [Workshop and a Tools Expert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR34p.jpg) that "knows a little something about tools and construction" (Isaiah Marcus)...

- By how much will the car's body and tire damage be repaired if I had it parked overnight?
- And if I have a car with one blown tire, how many nights will it take to repair it?

  - Is the length of repair time affected by how many tires are blown?
- Will cars that are on fire still be repaired (does it count as a body damage)? How long will it take? I'm asking because I have a car that is on fire that has been parked on the parking space for two days and nights now... but it's still on fire:

[image: screenshot of occurence described above]

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 levels of the Work Area (level 3 has 2 variants)

- Level 1: Work area - repairs your weapon only
- Level 2: Workshop - repairs weapon and partially repairs cars (flat tires, dented bodies)
- Level 3 (Machine Shop): repairs weapon and **fully** repairs cars (restores to mint condition)
- Level 3 (Munition Shop): Same as level 2, but allows you to make advanced explosives

Cars parked in marked parking spaces are instantly repaired at dawn.

Note that although you don't need a Construction expert to run a Machine Shop, you DO need one to **build** it.

You can refer to the game's [wiki page](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Work_Area) for more information.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer